# Getting ip adress away from network

Tags: router, ip

I use my old Iphone for remote controlling when i'm away from home. The problem is my service provider gives me dynamic ip adresses, so somethimes it changes itself. How can i know my home's actual ip adress away from home "free" ?

**Edit:**

I connect **FROM** my PC or Android device at work **TO** Iphone 3gs at home **VIA** VNC server.

I **DONT** want to leave a PC open at home for dynamic dns.

I **DONT** want to pay 30$/year for dydns.

I can connect my iphone. This is not the point. When my ip changes, i lose connection though.

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/847097/edit) your question and clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight **exactly** what you need or are trying to do. The others commenting on my answer would also like clarification ...

Comment: You **still** haven't told us "How is your iPhone (which is presumably at home) connected to your home network?". Where does the iPhone get it's IP address?

Comment: Becaus this is where i dont need help. Router has NAT, ports are forwarded, 192.x.x.x reserved for iphone.

Comment: So it is your router address that is changing? That is exactly what [Free Dynamic DNS](http://www.noip.com/free) is for ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I method I used to use many years ago before I got my static IP was as follows.

First off, find a service you can call to get your IP address.  For example, these days if you Google "Whats My IP" EG:

```
https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=whats+my+IP
```

You'll get a search page that looks something like the following:

[image]

Google's code is unfortunately a bit dense, but if you use a shell script and Wget, possibly with some grep calls, or even a custom script written in PHP that grabs Google's page and parses the result, you'll see that with a bit of work, it is possible to get the IP address from the page.

[image]

Of course, you don't have to use Google to get the IP, there are many other pages out there, that are dedicated to getting your IP, such as "www.whatsmyip.org"

[image]

Finally, if you have access to an external web server, you could even put a script on there, that simply just echos back the remote host address server variable in plain text.

The end result is that you get an IP address, it really doesn't matter which service you use, all that matters is that you automate a call to a host looking at your IP from the outside world, and you then parse that IP address out of the output returned to you.

Once you have that IP, you then automate your machine, to email that IP address to a public Email account such as GMail that you and your phone can access.

Put the script into some kind of timed job that checks say every 30 minutes or so and keeps a record of the last IP address issued, and one that only emails you if it changes.

Then when you want the IP address, simply log into the designated public email and look to see what the IP is.

### UPDATE

After doing a spot of research.  Namely looking at the source code in whats myip's page.  I was lead to take a look at:

```
http://www.realip.info/api/p/realip.php
```

If you pop this into a browser and hit return, here's what you'll get:

```
{"IP":"80.176.150.196"}
```

You IP address as a JSON object.  A JSON object that is just way too easy to parse :-)

### UPDATE 2

Ok, so in light that we now know that it's the phone that's being connected too, we can actually make this work.

However, before I go ahead with this, your phone MUST be behind and connected to your own network.  This will NOT work on a GSM/3g/4g or any other king of mobile phone operator network.

Steps to make this work

1. Create a standard html web page, add to said web-page, JQuery, and set it up so that the HTML code uses a meta-refresh tag to reload the page every so often.
2. Add some java script into said web page that calls 'realip.info' as I mentioned above.  If you do this code using jQuery and an Ajax get call, then in the function that fires when the call comes back, you'll get data with an object called 'IP'
3. In the same JavaScript have it then send that IP address somewhere that you can read it.  I'm not sure off the top of my head of any email solutions that can be accessed by java script, but again as mentioned earlier, if you have an external server of your own that runs a web site that you have access too, you could very easily use jQuery to post it to there.
4. Save this html page onto your SDcard or get it onto your phone in some other way, then connect your phone up as you would normally prior to remote controlling it.
5. Load the HTML into your phones browser, and allow it to just sit there, refreshing itself, calling the IP service, then sending the IP to where ever you asked it too.

To do this, you won't need a mac to develop any software for your IPhone, all you need is a smattering of HTML and JavaScript, the solution is also very portable and will work with any phone.

I could probably, very easy hack a script together to do this, but not at the moment as I'm not at my own PC, I might have a go at it later though :-)

### Update 3

Turns out it's quite easy to send Email using plain old JavaScript, using the GData API, details here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send

Comment: I dont have a mac computer to write that small app for my iphone but this is the best and only good answer i got so far, im approving this, thank you very much.

Comment: You don't write the app for your phone.  You write the app to run on the machine you want to know the IP address for.  That is, the machine you want to know the IP address that you'd like to log into. What operating system does that run?

Comment: Dude please dont you do that mistake too. Im connecting to a phone from computer, not to a computer from phone.

Comment: Right ok, no probs.  For ref your question doesn't read that way :-) but not to worry.  Let me just update my answer.  You'll see how you can get around that in a moment.

Comment: Pretty sure there's a site out there that provides the IP information in raw format.

Comment: @cybermonkey, read my answer... it's all in there :-)

Answer (score 4):

Reference [Free Dynamic DNS](http://www.noip.com/free)

> No-IP Free Dynamic DNS is our entry level service. Use
>   yourname.no-ip.info instead of a hard to remember IP address or URL to
>   access your computer remotely. Additionally, use our free dynamic DNS
>   update client to keep track of your dynamic IP address. You will
>   always be able to access your computer even if your IP address is
>   dynamically assigned.

Comment: The problem is im not accessing a computer, im accessing an old iphone 3gs.

Comment: You configure your computer to update a dns name with your current ip. This way, it doesn't matter if the ip changes, your dns will always be pointing to the correct ip

Comment: @EmreAcar No reason to be rude. Are you sure your English is perfect? You write that you want to use your iPhone for remote controlling and that you want to know your home's actual IP. This scenario is remote controlling your PC@Home from your iPhone@anywhere-mobile. Now in your comment you say you want to remote control your iPhone from your PC. So what do you really want?

Comment: If all you need is your home IP, the Free Dynamic DNS solution is your best bet. Some home router can 'report back' to the Dynamic DNS provider and get the 'current' home IP.

Comment: To your iPhone **from what device**?

Comment: How is your iPhone (which is presumably at home) connected to your home network? How are you accessing your iPhone and what do you expect to happen?